How Does AI-Generated Content Differ From Human-Written Content?
How Can I Determine if a Piece of Content Has Been Generated by AI?

Welcome to AI Stack Exchange. In general you cannot tell. If you give more specific context to what you are trying to do, that could help, and would make the question better. As it stands this question may get closed for being too broad and not clear. You could also add what tools and knowledge you have at your disposal - e.g. can you write and run your own models? We are a technical site for AI experts, and probably cannot answer this for you if you want some consumer product recommendation
